# Throwing exceptions to wcf service

Tags: wcf, exception

Can any one please explain me on how to throw a exception from a class library to a wcf service.
  Actually i have three layers
    1. Data Acess layer(Contails DB).
    2. BI Layer(WCF Class library)
    3. Asp.NET UI

Now my question is how to throw if some exception accurs in DAL to WCF BI Component.And How to throw that FaultException to UI.

Thanks in Advance,
Jane

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What's wrong with just throwing the exception?

Comment: If you still have questions, I suggest you check out [this][1] answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1520205/427653

Answer (score 0):

There is a very interesting article in codeproject about exception handling in 3-Tier architecture:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/expceptionhandling-3-tier.aspx

Basically every tier should be responsible for catching its own exceptions, logging the error/exception and providing just the necessary information to the next tier. For example: the UI should have just a user-friendly message without technical information.

The same idea can be adapted to the model you have implemented. Any error in DAL should be handled and propagated to the business tier. In your case the business service layer should throw a fault exception across the network with a custom user-friendly message that will be caught in the UI and probably displayed as a message.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I need one clarification.Here in dal i write as throw ex(some exception )but how to catch it in wcf service library am not getting any info related to it in net.