# Providing failure status for WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, httpresponse

I have a WCF service that I call the following way:

```
MyService client = new MyService();
bool result = client.MyServiceMethod(param1, param2);
```

Variable result is set to true or false to indicate success or failure. In case of success it is clear but in case of failure I need to get some details on what failed.

From my service I use

```
OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
response.StatusDescription = "Invalid parameter.";
return false;
```

My question is how do I retrieve the response description and is that the correct way to provide failure feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO it is best to define a custom class that you then return from your method.  This class would contain the details of any errors.  You do this using [DataContracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx).

A simplified example might be something like this...

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyResult DoSomething();
}

[DataContract]
public class MyResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorDetails { get; set; }
}


public class MyService : IMyContract
{
    public MyResult DoSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            return new MyResult { IsSuccess = true };
        }
        catch
        {
            return new MyResult { IsSuccess = false, ErrorDetails = "Bad things" };
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Including consuming code per comment.

```
var client = new MyService();
var results = client.DoSomething();

if (results.IsSuccess)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It worked");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Oops: {results.ErrorDetails}");
}
```

Comment: How would I then retrieve the details from the calling program?
Object result = client.MyServiveMethod(param1, param2); would not work

Comment: Added details to the posting.  Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you communicate problems to the client(s) using SOAP [MSDN:Faults](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx). Special advantage of faults is that WCF will ensure that your channel stays open after receiving fault message. By default, the service does not send any information explaining what happened. WCF does not reveal details about what the service does internally. See [MSDN:Specifying and Handling Faults in Contracts and Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details. Also see [SO:What exception type should be thrown with a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519984/what-exception-type-should-be-thrown-with-a-wcf-service)

For debugging purposes you can add  ServiceDebug behavior and set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults to true to get the stack trace (in non-production environments)